# I want to count the rows of a text file in a network location

Tags: batch-file

I have the following Script . But It gives me nothing. Please help:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" "\\dao10\RAC\RACDFR\BACKUP\out\20131203 \DEMANDCOMM_20131202_PS.txt" | find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
echo the row count of coutD.txt is %number%
pause
```

The Output is not coming . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^^^|` in place of `|`

`|` needs to be escaped within the `for /f`, and `^` needs to be escaped in the `set`.

(untested)

---

```dos
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" "\\dao10\RAC\RACDFR\BACKUP\out\20131203 \DEMANDCOMM_20131202_PS.txt" ^^^| find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
echo the row count of coutD.txt is %number%
pause
```

(untested)

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" "\\dao10\RAC\RACDFR\BACKUP\out\20131203\DEMANDCOMM_20131202_PS.txt" ^| find /C ":""
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" "\\m405\M405c\DEMANDCOMM_20131202_PS.txt" ^| find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('%cmd%') do set number=%%a
echo the row count of coutD.txt is %number%
GOTO :EOF
```

This gave me a count of the lines in the target file. Obviously, I can't test against your file, and I've left my path reference in place.

Note : only one `^` required and `%cmd%` in place of `!cmd!` and spurious space omitted from filepath.

Comment: It is doing the same thing as no output.-- @Magoo

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Be aware that the path you show has a space after the folder with a date

```
@echo off
set file="\\dao10\RAC\RACDFR\BACKUP\out\20131203\DEMANDCOMM_20131202_PS.txt"
type %file%
pause
for /f %%a in ('find /c /v "" ^< %file% ') do echo %%a lines
pause
```

Comment: Hello @foxidrive It's giving correct result for the local files but not network path.

Comment: That network path you gave - double check it.  You have to have read access to the file, and then it should work.

Comment: I am having read access when I am using client network. And I am currently in client network but still the network path is not working.

Comment: Try the changed code.  Tell me if there are any error messages.

Comment: its counting good . But type%file% section is looping the total file and the output is coming late in fact I have 3 MB file and it is coming very late. Any suggestion to make it fast and avoiding of showing the whole file as an output.